# Read words from file and put them in array

Tags: c, file

I want to read the words from a text file into an array.

Why does this code work with a 2D array (`a[50][50]`) but not with a 1D array (`a[50]`)?

This code prints what I want but it also print some other useless characters. What causes this?

```
void inputwords(){
    int i=0;
    char wrd[50];
    FILE * fptr;
    char fname[20]="txt.file";

    fptr=fopen(fname,"w");
    if(fptr==NULL) {
        printf("error in opening file!");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(wrd!='\0'){
        fgets(wrd,sizeof wrd,stdin);
        fprintf(fptr,"%s",wrd);
        if(wrd[i]=='*' && wrd[i+1]=='*' && wrd[i+2]=='*' && wrd[i+3]=='*' && 
         wrd[i+4]=='T' && wrd[i+5]=='E' && wrd[i+6]=='L' && wrd[i+7]=='O' && 
         wrd[i+8]=='S') {
            break;
        }
   }
   fclose(fptr);
   return;      
}

void readfile(){
    FILE *fptr;
    char a[50][50];
    int i=0;
    char fname[20]="txt.file";

    fptr=fopen(fname,"r");

    while(fgets(a[i],50,fptr)){
        i++;
    }
   for(i=0;i<50;i++){
       printf("%s",a[i]);
   }
   fclose(fptr);
   return;
};

main(){
    inputwords();
    readfile();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   for(i=0;i<50;i++){
       printf("%s",a[i]);
   }
```

This prints out the value of every pointer in a[50]. Once you reach past the char pointers which are actually set to point to something, you're just printing out the value of the pointer itself.

```
   for(int n=0; n<i; n++){
       printf("%s",a[n]);
   }
```

Would work.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the answer of Cowbolt, it works , and also wanted to ask you why do you have the line in inputwords() :

```
while(wrd!='\0') {
```

The condition of null character will never happen from user input. It is better to have clear instructions and say :

```
printf("Enter text (to finish input, type on a line of its own:****TELOS ):");
while (1) {    

/*be aware that your final i marks the position of string "****TELOS" */
/* so if you dont want it to output, have the n<i-1 in Cowbolt solution*/
```